# Could not load source 'dart:core/runtime/libobject_patch.dart': <source not available>

Tags: dart, flutter

I get this error:

> Could not load source 'dart:core/runtime/libobject_patch.dart': <source not available\>

[image: description of problem]

[image: description of problem]

[Project on GitHub](https://github.com/belichenk0andreyka/GitHubFirstApp/blob/Json_branch/lib/home_screen/leagues_list.dart)

I have two drop lists (one drop list with sports and the other with countries) and a list with leagues. The list with leagues should be sorted when selecting items in the drop lists, This error pops up when I select the city in the drop lists.

```
Future<List<ListTile>> _getListLeagues() async {
    http.Response data;
    String _str = "countrys";
    List<ListTile> listTiles = [];

    if ((_choiseCountry == null) & (_choisesport == null)) {
      data = await http
          .get("https://www.thesportsdb.com/api/v1/json/1/all_leagues.php");
      _str = "leagues";
    } else if ((_choisesport != null) & (_choiseCountry == null)) {
      data = await http.get(
          "https://www.thesportsdb.com/api/v1/json/1/search_all_leagues.php?s=$_choisesport");
    } else if ((_choiseCountry != null) & (_choisesport == null)) {
      data = await http.get(
          "https://www.thesportsdb.com/api/v1/json/1/search_all_leagues.php?c=$_choiseCountry");
    } else {
      data = await http.get(
          "https://www.thesportsdb.com/api/v1/json/1/search_all_leagues.php?c=$_choiseCountry&s=$_choisesport");
    }

    var jsonData = json.decode(data.body);

    for (var index in jsonData[_str]) {
      if (((_choisesport != null) & (_choisesport == index["strSport"])) |
          (_choisesport == null)) {
        ListTile list = ListTile(
          title: Text(index["strLeague"]),
          subtitle: Text(index["strSport"]),
        );
        listTiles.add(list);
      }
    }
    return listTiles;
  }
}

Future<List<DropdownMenuItem<String>>> _sports() async {
  var data = await http
      .get("https://www.thesportsdb.com/api/v1/json/1/all_sports.php");
  var jsonData = json.decode(data.body);

  List<DropdownMenuItem<String>> droplist = [];

  for (var sport in jsonData["sports"]) {
    droplist.add(DropdownMenuItem(
      child: Row(children: <Widget>[
        Text(sport["strSport"].toString()),
      ]),
      value: sport["strSport"],
    ));
  }
  return droplist;
}
```

Comment: Looks like https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/issues/34224

Comment: It's preferred to post error messages as text instead of screenshots to make them searchable.

Comment: Could not load source 'dart:core/runtime/libobject_patch.dart': <source not available>.

Comment: Any other suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

NoSuchMethodError issues usually occur if the class where the method is called from hasn't been initialized or if the method itself doesn't exist. In this case, as what have been previously mentioned in the comments, the issue seems to be similar with this [ticket](https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/issues/34224) posted on GitHub. Checking the thread, the issue should have been fixed. I suggest updating the Dart and Flutter SDK used on your app to resolve this issue.