# Could not load source 'dart:core-patch/errors_patch.dart': <source not available>

Tags: flutter, dart, testing

When you run testWidgets in flutter_test.dart

errors_patch.dart is automatically opened and
Could not load `source 'dart:core-patch/errors_patch.dart': <source not available>.` 
and the test fails with the statement.

widget_test.dart

```
import 'dart:async';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_riverpod/flutter_riverpod.dart';
import 'package:flutter_test/flutter_test.dart';
import 'package:go_router/go_router.dart';
import 'package:jintonic/data/subscription.dart';

import 'package:xxxxxxx/main.dart';
import 'package:xxxxxxx/view_pages/assets.dart';
import 'package:xxxxxxx/view_pages/config.dart';
import 'package:xxxxxxx/view_pages/title.dart';

void main() {
    testWidgets('Route title page', (tester) async {
      await tester.pumpWidget(const ProviderScope(child: MyApp()));
      expect(find.byWidgetPredicate((widget) => widget is TitlePage),
          findsOneWidget);
    });
    testWidgets('Tick action test', (tester) async {
      await tester.pumpWidget(const ProviderScope(
          child: MyApp()));
      final BuildContext context = tester
          .element(find.byWidgetPredicate((widget) => widget is TitlePage));

      context.go('/assets');
      await tester.pumpAndSettle();

      expect(find.text('0'), findsOneWidget);
      expect(find.text('10'), findsNothing);

      await tester
          .tap(find.byWidgetPredicate((widget) => widget is IconButton));
      await tester.pump(const Duration(seconds: 10));

      expect(find.text('10'), findsOneWidget);
      expect(find.text('0'), findsNothing);
  });
}
```

After examining the cases where errors occur and do not occur in the test, it was found that commenting out the following section would not result in an error.

```
import 'dart:async';

import 'package:flutter_riverpod/flutter_riverpod.dart';
import 'package:freezed_annotation/freezed_annotation.dart';

part 'subscription.freezed.dart';

final subscriptionProvider =
    StateNotifierProvider<SubscriptionStateNotifier, SubscriptionState>((ref) {
  return SubscriptionStateNotifier()
    ..init(tickerSubscriptionValue: DateTime.now());
});

final tickerSubscriptionValueProvider =
    Provider((ref) => ref.watch(subscriptionProvider).tickerSubscriptionValue);

class SubscriptionStateNotifier extends StateNotifier<SubscriptionState> {
  SubscriptionStateNotifier()
      : super(SubscriptionState(tickerSubscriptionValue: DateTime.now()));

  // final Ticker ticker = Ticker();
  StreamSubscription<int>? tickerSubscription;    

  void init({required DateTime tickerSubscriptionValue}) =>
      state = state.copyWith(tickerSubscriptionValue: tickerSubscriptionValue);

  void tickerStart() {
    tickerSubscription?.cancel();

    // tickerSubscription = ticker.tick().listen((duration) {
    //   state = state.copyWith(tickerSubscriptionValue: DateTime.now());
    // });
  }
}

// class Ticker {
//   Stream<int> tick() {
//     return Stream.periodic(
//       const Duration(seconds: 1),
//       (x) => x,
//     );
//   }
// }

@freezed
abstract class SubscriptionState with _$SubscriptionState {
  const factory SubscriptionState({required DateTime tickerSubscriptionValue}) =
      _SubscriptionState;
}
```

#### Checked.

・Q&A about `Could not load source 'dart:core-patch/errors_patch.dart': <source not available>.`  
-> Not found. Q&A about another file was found, but not helpful.
[Could not load source 'dart:core/runtime/libobject_patch.dart': <source not available>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54390922/could-not-load-source-dartcore-runtime-libobject-patch-dart-source-not-avai)

##### Reference Information

flutter doctor -v

```
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.1.0-0.0.pre.745, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19044.1706], locale ja-JP)
    • Flutter version 3.1.0-0.0.pre.745 at C:\Users\xxxxx\flutter
    • Upstream repository https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
    • Framework revision c248854d17 (5 days ago), 2022-05-16 23:57:08 -0400
    • Engine revision fce741dd83
    • Dart version 2.18.0 (build 2.18.0-120.0.dev)
    • DevTools version 2.13.1

[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 30.0.3)
    • Android SDK at C:\Users\xxxxx\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk
    • Platform android-31, build-tools 30.0.3
    • Java binary at: C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre\bin\java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_242-release-1644-b01)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[√] Android Studio (version 4.1)
    • Android Studio at C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio
    • Flutter plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter
    • Dart plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_242-release-1644-b01)

[√] VS Code (version 1.67.2)
    • VS Code at C:\Users\xxxxxx\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code
    • Flutter extension version 3.40.0

[√] Connected device (1 available)
    • AOSP on IA Emulator (mobile) • emulator-5554 • android-x86 • Android 9 (API 28) (emulator)

[√] HTTP Host Availability
    • All required HTTP hosts are available

• No issues found!
```

Best regards, please!

Answer (score 0):

you can use these two command in the terminal

```
flutter clean

flutter pub get
```

hope that helpful